# Power BI unintentionally converting a SSAS datekey integer into an excel serialised date

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a fact table with an Whole Number datekey, e.g. 20230207. I also have a date dimension which uses the same key. These are in an SSAS Tabular Model and I can see in Visual Studio that the numbers are whole numbers and represented correctly on screen.

When I connect in PBI to the model, if I drag Dim_Date[datekey] into the dashboard in Power BI I correctly get 20230207. When I drag in fct_items[datekey] I get something like 47083 which, from what I gather, is an [Excel Serialised Date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252). This seems to happen automatically on import, and it breaks the relationship.

Any ideas why PBI is automatically converting this to an Excel based serialised date?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you assign “Whole number” to a date field, it acts like a number. When you drag it into a view, it will be aggregated by default, and the default aggregation is SUM. To get a whole number to act like a date, you have to set the default to “Don’t summarize”. I don’t have an SSAS instance handy at the moment, but ideally you would set it in SSAS. This is what the setting looks like from the visual in Power BI, but again, ideally you would set this at the column level and I don’t think you can set that in Power BI, only SSAS.

[image]